# Apexcharts - Label colours do not match

Tags: apexcharts

I've assigned three different colours to the labels, but the colour dots always show up as Blue, Green and Yellow. I'm pretty sure I've done something wrong.

The code I've written is:

```
var pieSimpleChart = {
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  labels: ["IT", "Product Development", "Sales"],
  series: [2, 2, 6],
  fill: {
    colors: ["#447b40", "#cc7870", "#e74ce4"]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#task-pie-chart"), pieSimpleChart);
chart.render();
```

[image]

How can I match the labels to my selected colours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by removing "fill" option.
Now code looks like:

```
    var pieSimpleChart = 
    {
        chart: 
        {
            height: 350,
            type: 'pie',
        },
        legend: 
        {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        labels: ["IT", "Product Development", "Sales"],
        series: [2, 2, 6],
        colors: ["#447b40", "#cc7870", "#e74ce4"]
    }
```

Comment: Can someone please help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590738/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-lines-of-chart-its-axis-lines-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

***Add colour tag after labels.*** *With this you can use colour of your choice.*

```
var pieSimpleChart = {
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  labels: ["IT", "Product Development", "Sales"],
  colors: ["#447b40", "#cc7870", "#e74ce4"],
  series: [2, 2, 6],
  fill: {
    colors: ["#447b40", "#cc7870", "#e74ce4"]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#task-pie-chart"), pieSimpleChart);
chart.render();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `backgroundColor` instead off `fill: colors`.

Also, you should use the [dataset](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/?h=dataset) object for passing the values:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["IT", "Product Development", "Sales"],
        datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: [
                "#ff0000",
                "#00ff00",
                "#0000ff"
            ],
            data: [2, 2, 6]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can someone please help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590738/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-lines-of-chart-its-axis-lines-in-angular

Comment: your answer is for charts.js the question referrers to Apex charts